# How To Change Color Of Icon And Poly Line At Run Time By Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, polyline

You Have edited script according to v2 i am getting this error on using that script pic attached on line 154

```
GEvent.addListener(window.polyline, 'click', function() {
                                    window.polyline.setOptions(options: { strokeColor: 'blue' });
```

[image: You Have edited script according to v2 i am getting this error on using that script pic attached]How can we change color of icon and polyline by click on running application? My code is as follows. It has no error. How can I do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace GoogleMap
{
    // A sample project by Ghaffar khan

    public partial class Map : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet1TableAdapters.LocationsTableAdapter da = new GoogleMap.DataSet1TableAdapters.LocationsTableAdapter();
            DataSet1.LocationsDataTable table = new DataSet1.LocationsDataTable();
            da.Fill(table);
            BuildScript(table);
            //GooglePolyline PL1 = new GooglePolyline();

        }
        private void BuildScript(DataTable tbl)
        {
            String Locations = "";
            foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
            {
                // bypass empty rows        
                if (r["Latitude"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
                    continue;

                string Latitude = r["Latitude"].ToString();
                string Longitude = r["Longitude"].ToString();
                // create a line of JavaScript for marker on map for this record    
                Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")));";

            }

            // construct the final script
            js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            function initialize() {
                              if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 2); 
                                map.openInfoWindowHtml ( new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 'Serif<br>Pakistan');
                                " + Locations + @"
                                map.setUIToDefault();

// Create an array with points  
var points = [  
   new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703),  
   new GLatLng(24.914463, 67.0965958),  
   new GLatLng(24.86588, 67.06089),  
new GLatLng(24.9726753, 67.06638),
new GLatLng(24.840023, 67.24285),
new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703)
];  

// Create a new polyline  
var polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);  

// Add the polyline to the map using map.addOverlay()  
map.addOverlay(polyline);
var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667))  
// 

                              }
                            }


                            </script> ";
        }       

    }
}
```

//////The Script According to GergL is,///////

```
           js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            function initialize() {
                              if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                                window.polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7); 
                                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 2); 
                                map.openInfoWindowHtml ( new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 'Serif<br>Pakistan');
                                " + Locations + @"
                                map.setUIToDefault();
google.maps.event.addListener(window.polyline, 'click', function() {
    window.polyline.setOptions(options: { strokeColor: 'blue' });
});
// Create an array with points  
var points = [  
   new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703),  
   new GLatLng(24.914463, 67.0965958),  
   new GLatLng(24.86588, 67.06089),  
new GLatLng(24.9726753, 67.06638),
new GLatLng(24.840023, 67.24285),
new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703)
];  

// Create a new polyline  
var polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);  

// Add the polyline to the map using map.addOverlay()  
map.addOverlay(polyline);                          
                              }
                            }
google.maps.event.addListener(window.polyline, 'click', function() {
    window.polyline.setOptions(options: { strokeColor: 'blue' });
});
                            </script> ";
```

But i am getting error .. .Object Expected in line 47 in script where i use click method in that line hopes for your help !

You Have edited script according to v2 i am getting this error on using that script pic attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your `polyline` variable in the `initialize()` function to a globally accessible variable, and then use the [`setOptions()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline) method on it to set the new colour in your click event handler (in javascript).

e.g. if you changed the line in `initialise()` from this:

```
var polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);
```

to this:

```
window.polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);
```

And then wanted to have it change to blue when clicked, you would add code like:

```
GEvent.addListener(window.polyline, 'click', function() {
    window.polyline.setOptions(options: { strokeColor: 'blue' });
});
```

I haven't tested this, btw. But it should help you get on the right track.

EDIT: Here is what I think your script should be:
EDIT 2: Updated to work with API v2, though be aware Google strongly encourages you to migrate to the new V3 on both the [V2 documentation page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/events.html) and the [V3 documentation page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html).

```
js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            function initialize() {
                              if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 2);
                                map.openInfoWindowHtml ( new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 'Serif<br>Pakistan');
                                " + Locations + @"
                                map.setUIToDefault();
                                // Create an array with points  
                                var points = [  
                                   new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703),  
                                   new GLatLng(24.914463, 67.0965958),  
                                   new GLatLng(24.86588, 67.06089),  
                                   new GLatLng(24.9726753, 67.06638),
                                   new GLatLng(24.840023, 67.24285),
                                   new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703)
                                ];  

                                // Create a new polyline  
                                window.polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);  
                                GEvent.addListener(window.polyline, 'click', function() {
                                    window.polyline.setOptions(options: { strokeColor: 'blue' });
                                });
                                // Add the polyline to the map using map.addOverlay()  
                                map.addOverlay(window.polyline);                          
                              }
                            }
                        </script> ";
```

Comment: Where should i add this code for click function ??? either in my script or in code behind??

Comment: Either. You are using presumably a literal control on the page at the moment to render out your javascript, which will work, but isn't the best way to do it.

The click function, like all interactions with the Google Maps javascript API is done, obviously, in Javascript. The best place for you is to add the last 3 lines of code in my answer right after the first single line of code in my answer (i.e. in your code behind).

Was I correct in my guess that you wanted to polyline to change colour when you click it?

Comment: When I say "Either", I mean you can either use your code behind to render out javascript like you are doing already, or you can have a separate function that you define, in say a javascript file you include in your page, and then render out a call to that function from the code behind. Does that make sense?

Comment: you are right i wanna change icon and polyline color on click dosent matter from where the function will call either from code behind or aspx page

Comment: now My script according to your help has changed to that script as i mentioned in my question i edited my post and mentioned there please see above !

Comment: I have edited my answer to what I think your code should be. Note that I am adding the listener (think of like a "click event handler" in Javascript) after I initialise the `window.polyline` variable.

Comment: @Syed Raza, I just noticed I was using the API v3 syntax in my answer. I have now updated my answer to work with API v2, though I encourage you to follow Google's advice and migrate to using V3 when possible.

Comment: i am getting error using this script on the Gevent add listner line I have Attached Pic In My First post and the line 154 is of Gevent listner line that is causing error :(

Comment: I'm not sure that is where the error actually is. IE's line numbers are often wrong, I'm sorry to say. Do you have Firefox and Firebug? If so, does the Console in Firebug show any errors? I cannot spot any place in my script that is missing a right parentheses.